# Can you defer ajax setup in jquery 1.5?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have something like this

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
```

I am wonder can you do ajaxSetup like you can do $.ajax

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
    .success(function() { alert("success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

So could I do

```
 var a =    $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        })
```

then

```
a.success(function() { alert("success"); })
```

I have not had a chance to try to this out yet. Once I have few minutes I going to try this but if someone knows that would be good too. I also don't see anything in the documentation.

Comment: Try it out first please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, no you won't be able to do that - [`.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup) isn't a [defered object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), unlike [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) *as of jQuery v1.5*. So you will just get an error saying the object doesn't have the methods.

If what you are trying to do is setup things to happen with every `.ajax()` call *(`.ajaxSetup()` sets up defaults for all `.ajax()` calls)*. You can access global ajax callbacks like:

[`$.ajaxComplete(function(){alert("complete");})`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete)

[`$.ajaxError(function(){alert("error");})`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError)

[`$.ajaxSuccess(function(){alert("success");})`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess)

if you want to perform actions on **ALL** ajax calls if that is what you are aiming for? You will also have access to all the callback parameters:

*`.ajaxError(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError)`*

---

*Updates to follow up comments:*

As per the [docs for .ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

> **Note:** Global callback functions should
>   be set with their respective global
>   Ajax event handler
>   methods: [.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart), [.ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop),
>   [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete), [.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError),
>   [.ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess), [.ajaxSend()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend) rather
>   than within the options object for
>   [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

So it looks like there is no global handler for the statusCode like the callback added in 1.5. However again as per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> If the request is successful, the
>   status code functions take the same
>   parameters as the success callback; if
>   it results in an error, they take the
>   same parameters as the error callback.

So I would think, you could use for example:

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    if (xhr.status == "200")
        alert("Your call to: '"+settings.url+"' was a success (status code: "+xhr.status+")");
});

$('body').ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    if (xhr.status == "401")
        alert("You are not logged into the remote page!");
    if (xhr.status == "404")
        alert("The remote page could not be found: '"+settings.url+"'(status code: "+xhr.status+")");
});
```

Take a look at the [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/H6VYW/1/) it shows a successful and an un-successful `.ajax()` call - showing local and global actions, including dealing with different statusCodes.

Comment: How would you do statusCode? I tried $.ajaxStatusCode but that does not seem to work. I get a error when I try.

Comment: It looks like the statusCode has been missed from the global range added. But it is just a convenient way to access the status code which is available to success and error - you just have to be cleaver how you use it. Take a look at the update to see if that helps you at all.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the `AjaxSetup(..)` modifies the `jQuery.AjaxSettings` object with your choices. So you could write

```
 jQuery.ajaxSettings.cache=false
```

to achieve the same result.

More detail can be found here: http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2010/06/jquery-unveiled-ajaxsettings-class.html